# Results count in facet is displaying wrongly in Endeca

Tags: facet, faceted-search, endeca

I am doing a search implementation using Endeca and displaying facets along with result count for each facet value. Initial page load looks good as I am getting all the count correctly. The issue is when I follow the below scenario,

Initial Facet Display

- Colour
- Blue (2)
- Green (4)
- Black (5)

if I select blue, this is like

- Blue (2) -- with checkbox selected
- Green (4)
- Black (5)

Now if I am selecting green, it is like

- Blue (6) -- with checkbox selected
- Green (6) -- with checkbox selected
- Black (5)

If I select black now, all the facet value count will show as 11, that is adding 5 to it.

No customization done at Endeca side to retrieve the facet count, using OOTB. Only 2 changes that I can think of causing the issue, but no solution in my mind to fix that.

1) Made implicitDimension as true since we will be having one root category and wants to retrieve entire category hierarchy
2) Indexing done based on two languages in 1 MDEX, i.e. it will be double of actual catalog size (I dont think this an issue since we are getting correct count at the initial load)

Any thoughts or solutions?

Comment: Have you tried to replicate this in the endeca reference application? Also, show us the code fragment used to display the facet counts. The two changes you refer to are unlikely to be the cause.

Comment: '_<c:forEach var="refinement" items="${content.refinements}">
  <li data-count="${refinement.count}">
  <label data-href="${link}" for="${content.name}-${count}">
  <input type="checkbox" name="${content.name}-${count}" id="${content.name}-${count}" data-label="${refinement.label}">
      <span>${refinement.label}${bracOpen}${refinement.count}${bracClose}</span>      
 </label>
  </li>       
      
</c:forEach>_'  @radimpe this is the code snippet and I cant see any issues in JSP REF application also I am not customizing the refinement count in any handlers as well.

Comment: @radimpe another thing I have noticed is that each time I select a refinement, the count displays is total number of records of selected values, not individual.

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine. Did you create your pipeline through `Developer Studio`? Perhaps you set some of your dimensions up as `Multi select`?

Comment: @radimpe yes it is multi select, we did not create any pipeline through studio

Comment: Is that `Multi Select - And` or `Multi Select - Or`? Also, if you change it to `Multi Select - None` do you have the same problem?

Comment: @radimpe It is Multi Select -or and if there is no multi select then its works fine. Basically it will return no of results matching the refinements are par with the number displayed.

Comment: What is your desired behavior? You described what happens, but you didn't describe what you WANT to happen. It'll make it easier to answer your question if people know exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your desired behavior is and I suggest you edit your question to include that, but I will point you at a useful resource for understanding Multiselect-OR refinement counts (since it's kind of confusing to understand). Check out the [MDEX Developer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55324_01/Mdex.651/pdf/DevGuide.pdf), pg. 185 (Refinement counts for multiselect-or dimensions).

Now, I know I don't know anything about your data or your needs, but I will also suggest this: if you want some other behavior for refinement counts, you might want to consider whether Multiselect-OR is the right choice for that dimension. Multiselect-OR is more expensive than single dimensions and also doesn't make it faster for users to find what they want because it always increases the size of the result set instead of shrinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Endeca actually guesses at the refinement count using statistics.  You can alter the number of records it uses to 'guess' the refinement count by altering the --esampmin flag on the dgraph.

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/IAPAdmin/src/rbdv_flags_dgraph.html) for more details.